# Appending file in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload a file using `Kendo Grid`, using `Kendo Upload` is not an option because model and the file are related and upload cannot happen separately.

I've considered two options, having a `HttpPostedFileBase` field in the model and setting it in the `save` event. And receiving that file as an argument in the `action method` and using `Data` method of `update` and `create` configurations. Both of these ways will end up with client-side `kendo` exceptions like `JavaScript runtime error: Argument not optional`.

I'll be grateful if you could guide me with this.

`Action method` signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, myViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Client side functions:

```
var descRes = new function () {
  this.onSave = function (e) {
        var u2 = $('#upload2');
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $('#upload2').get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0)
            data.append('file', files[0]);

        e.model.set('ImageFile', files[0]); // I have tried to set it to `data` too
    };

    this.getFile = function (e) {
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $('#upload2').get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0)
            data.append('file', files[0]);

        return { file: data };
        // return data; // I have also tried this, or returning `files[0]` directly
    };
};
```

Grid's configuration:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<viewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    // removed for brevity 
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Events(e => e
        .Save("descRes.onSave")
    )
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(x => x.Id);
        })
        .Read(r => r.Action("Read", "AssetRes").Data("descRes.readData"))
        .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "AssetRes").Data("descRes.getFile"))
        .Update(u => u.Action("Update", "AssetRes").Data("descRes.getFile"))
        .Destroy("Delete", "AssetRes")
    )
)
```

I'm also trying to use `Kendo Upload` separately and use the file's name in the grid's model as in [this example](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/367694_gridUploadPopupTemplate.zip?sfvrsn=0), the problem is that the upload object doesn't have any functions, `files` and `getFiles` are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom grid editor for the upload. The upload should work asyncly, so you could save your row only when the file is uploaded. In your model you then write the TempFileID returned by the upload. 
This way I created grids with uploads and further data. It's a little bit tricky, but possible.